# Unable to find image '7111.mithun:latest' locally Error response from daemon: repository 7111.mithun not found: does not exist or no pull access

Tags: docker

$ docker run 7111.mithun
Unable to find image '7111.mithun: latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: repository 7111.mithun not found: does not exist or no pull access.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.

I got this error when I try to run the image .Can anyone able to provide any solutions

Comment: do you have 711.mithun image in your local? check "docker images"

Comment: i don't have this image if i run docker image   suthakar79@Ravisankar MINGW64 ~
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

suthakar79@Ravisankar MINGW64 ~
$

Comment: In that case, build the image or pull from the dockerhub or private repository if its already exist there. And real gotcha here is "image tag", if you don't specify the tag, it will assume latest, for instance  7111.mithun: latest. good luck